# SSH connection could not be established rhc server

Tags: windows, ssh, openshift

I get an error while I try to run the command `rhc server`.

```
SSH connection could not be established .
```

[image]

.ssh folder has both private and public keys.

[image]

How do I fix this?

I did run the chmod command as well . It executed with no errors and no output on console. and yet I get the same error nexttime when I run rhc setup.

Comment: What version of ruby & the net-ssh gem are you using? If you are using ruby 2.2, try using ruby 1.9.3 or 2.1, also try using the non-beta version of the net-ssh gem.

Comment: @coreydaley:  That solved the problem. Though it still asks me to run chmod command and I did.but it gives nothing out on console. Anything to worry about or I am good to go now? :)